# Resharper 9 Ultimate: No tests found in file

Tags: unit-testing, resharper

What can I do to get my new unit tests appear in Resharper Unit Test Explorer ? 
I have tried clear Resharper Cache, restart VS2013 as administrator and rebuild solution. Still no luck - Resharper can't see my unit test.

I'm running Resharper Ultimate 9.2 with VS2013.

This is a sample of my unit test class:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class MyUnitTestBase<ITestComponent>: where 
ITestComponent:TestComponent, new() 
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyAssertion()
    {           
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you open the Unit Test Explorer under ReSharper menu? The Test menu at top is the VS built in one and won't work for you.

Comment: Yep I use the Resharper -> Unit Tests -> Unit Tests , not the VS built-in Test menu .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out: it's because that my test class is `abstract`.

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class MyUnitTestBase<ITestComponent>: where 
ITestComponent:TestComponent, new() 
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyAssertion()
    {           
    }
}
```

Of course abstract class can't have instance and thus Resharper is unable to detect it. Once I create a subclass for it, the unit tests are now showing:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests: MyUnitTestBase<TestComponentVersionA> 
{    
}
```